# Use the Riemann sum with $n=3$ terms and the midpoint point rule to approximate $\int_0^{1/10} \sin(x^2) \ dx$

Tags: calculus

Yesterday I asked a question in regards to the Riemann sum, I wanted to learn one or two.. I later learned that the question did not have any need for the Reimann sum, hence I went ahead to search and look for one so that i can do it and learn from it.

Use the Riemann sum with $n=3$ terms and the midpoint point rule to approximate $$\int_0^{1/10} \sin(x^2) \ dx$$ you do not need to simplify the sum. Any help or hints on how I would approach this will be appreciated.

Comment: Could your post which version of the Riemann sum (the definition) you'd like to use? Also, posting an attempt at solution can help use identify where your problem is.

Comment: I dont know how to use the tex symbol of the sum. Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Break $[0,1/10]$ into three equal pieces; evaluate the function at the midpoint of each piece; add the results up; multiply the sum by the length of the pieces (i.e. by $1/30$).

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin\big(x^2\big)~dx ~=~ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\cos\big(x^2\big)~dx ~=~ \sqrt{\frac\pi2}~$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to think of these "rules" geometrically instead of intimidating summations. Recall the idea behind Riemann sums -- approximating the area under a curve by means of rectangles. The tricky part is determining what the height of the rectangles should be (widths are usually uniform). Most often, techniques are named by their methods of assigning heights. As for your case, the midpoint rule assigns heights by picking the midpoint of the base of each rectangle and evaluating the function at that point. This point should be thought of as a 'representative' height of the function around that area.

The abstraction in the first paragraph should be clear in the following computation. First, divide $[0,\frac{1}{10}]$ into $n = 3$ intervals of length $\Delta x = \left(\frac{1}{10} - 0\right)/\,3 = \frac{1}{30}$. 
$$\left[0,\frac{1}{10}\right] = \left[0,\frac{1}{30}\right] \cup \left[\frac{1}{30},\frac{2}{30}\right] \cup \left[\frac{2}{30},\frac{1}{10}\right].$$
Now, take the midpoints of each subinterval. Labeling them $x_1,x_2,x_3$, we have
$$\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3\right\} = \left\{\frac{1}{60},\frac{1}{20},\frac{1}{12}\right\}.$$
The heights of the rectangles at the $x_i$ are
$$\left\{\sin\left(x_1^2\right),\sin\left(x_2^2\right),\sin\left(x_3^2\right)\right\} = \left\{\sin\left(\frac{1}{3600}\right),\sin\left(\frac{1}{400}\right),\sin\left(\frac{1}{144}\right)\right\}.$$
Now we use the fact that the area of a rectangle is width * height to compute the approximation.
$$\int_0^{1/10} \sin\left(x^2\right) \,\mathrm{d}x  \approx \sum_{i=1}^3 \left(\Delta x\right) \sin\left(x_i^2\right) = \frac{1}{30}\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{3600}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{400}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{144}\right)\right).$$
As requested, I did not simplify. I recommend drawing a picture of an aribtrary function, dividing the interval $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals, and drawing rectangles with differing heights to help you understand what is happening.

Comment: Why did you multiply by $x_1,x_2,x_3$ instead of by $\Delta x$?

Comment: Ah sorry typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to compare your numerical result with the *exact* result, this integral evaluates to:

$$ \int^{1/10}_0  \sin{x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x =  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \, S \left( \frac{1}{5 \sqrt{2\pi}} \right) \approx 0.000333331,$$ where $S(z)$ is a [***Fresnel (sine) integral***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Hope you find this useful. Cheers!